# pytest-mock: mocking not working when done without fixture and import is global

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm using PyCharm Pro and I have Python interpreter configured to remote interpreter from Docker.

My project structure is like this

```
├── helpers.py
├── package1
│   ├── helper_functions.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── package2
│   ├── helpers_functions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── package1
    │   ├── conftest.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── test_helper_functions.py
    └── package2
        ├── conftest.py
        ├── __init__.py
```

I'm using `pytest` and `pytest-mock`.

I define a test in `tests/package1/test_helper_functions.py` to test `package1.helper_functions.helper_func1` that calls a function `helpers.some_long_operation` this function I want to mock.

So I do.

```
# package1/helper_functions.py

from helpers import some_long_operation

def helper_func1():
    return some_long_operation()
```

```
# tests/package1/test_helper_functions.py

from package1.helper_functions import helper_func1

def test_helper_func1(mocker):
    mocker.patch("helpers.some_long_operation", return_value={})
    assert helper_func1() == {}
```

So when I execute the test the original `helpers.some_long_operation` gets called.

However when I create a *fixture* in `conftest.py` and import the function locally in the test function the mock works and original function isn't called.

So I create a fixture in `tests/package1/conftest.py`

```
# tests/package1/conftest.py

import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def mocked_some_long_operation(mocker):
    mocker.patch("helpers.some_long_operation", return_value={})
```

And I use this fixture in test and import `package1.helper_functions.helper_func1` locally inside the function.

```
# tests/package1/test_helper_functions.py


def test_helper_func1(mocked_some_long_operation):
    from package1.helper_functions import helper_func1
    assert helper_func1() == {}
```

**Now I'm OK that this works for now but I'm curious as to why it happens.**

Comment: You are patching the wrong reference - see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). Something like `patch("package1.helper_functions.some_long_operation")` should work instead.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yeah this was the missing link, but why does it work when I move this to `conftest.py`.

Comment: Because the import of `conftest.py` occurs before `package1/helper_functions.py`.